# Sync vs async for file write in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, writefile

I've recently been told sync functions completly block the app while they are in use. That is why I want to convert the functionality of the code below to async.
I recive an optimized image, save the file as a .webp format and delete the old nonoptimized one. Than the new `user_file` gets saved to a database right after this.

```
fs.writeFileSync(req.file.path + '.webp', data);
user_file = user_file + '.webp';
fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
```

If I just convert it to async like this it just goes on and inserts the old `user_file`:

```
fs.writeFile(req.file.path + '.webp', data, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    user_file = user_file + '.webp';
  });
});  // I could just put user_file = user_file + '.webp'; here but I also want to make sure that it was successfully saved before moving on
```

How do I keep this async but still wait for the functions to be fully completed before moving on to db insertions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fs.Promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) API instead of a classic with a callback.

```js
await fsPromises.writeFile(req.file.path + '.webp', data)
```